# How can I conditionally get values from XML w/ElementTree?

Tags: python, elementtree

I have XML and I need to extract some values, and if these values don't exists I want "N/A".

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DEF xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="FF.xsd">
    <FOLD SERV="TRYING" VERSION="918" PLATFORM="UNIX" GROUP_NAME="UNIX" MODIFIED="False" LAST_UPLOAD="20220117145134UTC" TYPE="1" USED_BY_CODE="0">
        <JOB JOBID="835" APP="TRY" JOBNAME="JOBA" DESC="Extrac607" TYPE="db" FORM="Databases" CM_VER="N/A" MULTY_AGENT="N" VERSION_SERIAL="1" PARENT_FOLDER="UNIX">
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%TYPE_DB" VALUE="Open Query" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%APPLOG" VALUE="N" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%ACCOUNT" VALUE="ONLINE" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%TYPE" VALUE="Oracle" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%VERS" VALUE="11g" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%LENGHT" VALUE="16" />
        </JOB>
        <JOB JOBID="839" APP="TRY" JOBNAME="JOBB" DESC="Extrac617" TYPE="db" FORM="Databases" CM_VER="N/A" MULTY_AGENT="N" VERSION_SERIAL="1" PARENT_FOLDER="UNIX">
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%TYPEDB" VALUE="Open Query" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%ACCOUNT" VALUE="ONLINE" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%TYPE" VALUE="Oracle" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%VERS" VALUE="11g" />
            <VARIABLE NAME="%%LENGHT" VALUE="16" />
        </JOB>
    </FOLD>
</DEF>
```

Here is my code:

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree
from contextlib import redirect_stdout
from collections import Counter

import xlsxwriter
import pprint
import os
import datetime

begin_time = datetime.datetime.now()
print(datetime.datetime.now())
    
###VARIABLES RUTASL   
fileXML= 'C:\\xxxx\\completa.xml'
cont=0
path= 'C:\\xxxxxx\\todo.csv'
outputExcel = 'C:\\xxxxxxx\\salida.xlsx'
file2 = 'C:\\xxxxxxxx\\todo.csv'




try:
    os.remove(path)
except OSError as e:  ## if failed, report it back to the user ##
    print ("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))

try:
    os.remove(outputExcel)
except OSError as e:  ## if failed, report it back to the user ##
    print ("Error: %s - %s." % (e.filename, e.strerror))




with open(fileXML, encoding="utf8") as f:
    tree = ElementTree.parse(f)

    
# using getchildren() within root and check if tag starts with keyword 
#print [node.text for node in root.getchildren() if node.tag.startswith('%%FTP-LPATH')]
root = tree.getroot()
set_tipos= set()
lista_tipos = list()

for node in tree.iter('JOB'):


    name = node.attrib.get('JOBNAME')
    appl_type = node.attrib.get('TYPE')
    appl_form = node.attrib.get('FORM')
    

    if appl_form:
        set_tipos.add(appl_form)
        lista_tipos.append(appl_form)
    else:
        set_tipos.add(appl_type)
        lista_tipos.append(appl_type)
        
     
    
print('#####################################')


cuenta1 = Counter(lista_tipos)
print(cuenta1)

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook(outputExcel)
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('Resumen')
bold =workbook.add_format({'bold':1})
centrado =workbook.add_format({'center_across':1})
centrado = workbook.add_format({'bold': True, 'center_across': True})

headings = list()
datos = list()
listaBD = list()
pointDB=1

for key, value in cuenta1.items():
    # scores = 0
    print(key)
    headings.append(key)
    datos.append(value)



if 'Databases' in headings:
    print('Existe base de datos')
    
    for node4 in tree.iterfind(".//JOB[@TYPE = 'db']"): 
        listaBD.clear()
        name = node4.attrib.get('JOBNAME')
        appl_type = node4.attrib.get('TYPE')
        listaBD.append(name)
        listaBD.append(appl_type)
        for node4 in tree.iterfind(".//JOB/VARIABLE[@NAME='%%TYPE_DB']"):
            a=0 

        value = node4.attrib.get('VALUE', 'N/A')
        listaBD.append(value) 


        worksheet.write_row('A'+str(pointDB),listaBD)
        pointDB += 1


        node4.clear()

else:
    print('Don't exists')

print(datetime.datetime.now() - begin_time)

workbook.close()

                ...................
```

This works, but I have 6 if(s) in every case, and the program is very slow.
I've edited the main code. It seems problem is the size of xml. XML has 50 MB.
The output is:
[image: Output]
How else can I conditionally get these values?

Comment: I only count 3 if-statements. Are there more you're not showing? I've added a solution that gets rid of two that you're showing us.

Comment: Also, how are you measuring its speed? Why do you think the if-statements are making it slow? How slow is "very slow"?

Comment: there are more if(s) that I have not written.  In each for I search a value and I use an if to check if the value is empty.

Answer (score 2):

I see at least two things you can change to remove if-blocks.

### A more specific X-Path

I see this "if type matches do everything, else skip" branch:

```py
appl_type = node4.attrib.get('TYPE')
if appl_type == 'db':
```

You can avoid that by putting the check for `@TYPE` into your top X-Path:

```py
for node4 in tree.iterfind(".//JOB[@TYPE = 'db']"):
```

### Default getter

You're getting an attrib value and deciding what to do based on whether it's `None` or not:

```py
if node4.attrib.get('VALUE') is None:
    print("don't exists")
    listaBD.append('N/A')
else:
    print("Existe")
    listaBD.append(node4.attrib.get('VALUE'))
```

Use a *default value* in the `get()` method if it's `None` and avoid the check:

```py
value = node4.attrib.get('VALUE', 'N/A')
listaBD.append(value)
```

### Miscellaneous

This doesn't remove an if-block, but it restructures and makes the code a little easier to follow:

```py
if 'DB' not in headings:
    quit()  # or `return` from a function/method... don't go on

print('DB Exists')
```

Doesn't remove the `if`, but now everything is not nested under it.

Here's my complete edit of your original code

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

tree = ET.parse('input.xml')
headings = ['DB']
listaBD = []

if 'DB' not in headings:
    quit()  # or `return` from a function/method... don't go on

print('DB Exists')

for node4 in tree.iterfind(".//JOB[@TYPE = 'db']"):
    print('//////////////////////////')
    print(node4.tag, node4.attrib)
    name = node4.attrib.get('JOBNAME')
    appl_type = node4.attrib.get('TYPE')
    
    print(name + " " + appl_type)
    for node4 in tree.iterfind(".//JOB/VARIABLE[@NAME='%%TYPE_DB']"):
        print('TIPO')
        print(node4.attrib.get('VALUE'))

    value = node4.attrib.get('VALUE', 'N/A')
    listaBD.append(value)

    node4.clear()
    for node4 in tree.iterfind(".//JOB/VARIABLE[@NAME='%%DBSCHEMA']"):
        print(node4)
```

Comment: It's around tenth time when I look on data, then look on code in question, then look on your code and I still have not find an answer why is it implemented in such a weird way. Logic says that if you need to parse XML with several `<JOB>` nodes each containing set of `<VARIABLE>` nodes you want it to have some kind of hierarchy structure. Instead you *(and question author)* are iterating over all `<JOB>` nodes, then for some unknown reason for each found node execute bunch of inner loops which iterate over all `<VALUE>` nodes with certain attribute values and save all into a flat list. Chaos.

Comment: thanks for all your suggestion, it seems that the code is slow because I have  some for(s) to search patters with iterfind.

Comment: @OlvinRoght The XML have JOBs with distinct 'type' and the JOBs that have the same type, could have different variable names... so some of them could have type_db and other could not. So I should find all ocurrences and when the JOB don't have the variable name should put "N/A". After these, I store the values in a list because then I use a excel (xlswriter)   to put the data

Comment: @OlvinRoght, I don't really understand OP's intent, either. But I do understand that they, or anyone, could value from being more specific with the X-Path and in general using defaults on `get()`... I'm just trying to address their basic concern.

Comment: @defekas17, it would be much easier if you'll add your expected output to question.

Comment: @Olvin Roght. I've written all code in the main post. I think problem is xml is very big (50 mB) because I've only used two iterfind and time consumption is about 5 minutes

Comment: @defekas17, you haven't added any sample of **output** you want to get from this data.

Comment: @OlvinRoght I attach in the main post the ouptut

Comment: @defekas17, maybe you can change logic to something like [this](https://cutt.ly/YIIjSNY).

Comment: @defekas17, or [this](https://cutt.ly/gIIllH3)

Comment: Thanks @OlvinRoght but how store file about 50 MB in a string to can use fromString?

Comment: @defekas17, it's not necessary, you can load it from file as you currently do in your code, I've used `fromstring()` just fro example.

Comment: @OlvinRoght wooo! very faster than my code. But I don't now why. I think is that you use find instead iterfind right?

Comment: @defekas17, read first comment under this answer. Part with *"Logic says.."*

Comment: @defekas17, now you understand your mistake?

Comment: @OlvinRoght by what I see I should use list with for to find the elements and use find instead iterfind

Comment: @defekas17, you called `iterfind()` on root node every time, so every call caused search for every node in entire file

Answer (score 0):

I see you iterating over the XML node-by-node a lot, you even do two complete passes over it, once to build the lists and sets for the `headings`, and then again to try and find values.  I could see that taking some time, but I still don't understand exactly why this is so slow for you.

I suggest you break your problem down into separate steps:

1. Read over the XML once, building up a simple Python-list of rows with ALL the data... don't try to be selective
2. Filter the list of rows
3. Write the filtered list (to your Excel workbook)

How you pull the data out of the XML also can be improved, iterating over every node and checking if the node is what you want is wasteful.  Use `find('NODE-NAME')` to go for exactly what you want.

Here's how I'd do this:

#### Read the XML once, gather *ALL* data

```py
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

# Pre-define the values you want/expect, note that Type_DB and Account are already 'N/A' (as placeholders)
Row_Tmpl = {'JobID': None, 'JobName': None,
            'Type': None, 'Form': None, 'Type_DB': 'N/A', 'Account': 'N/A'}

# Don't need `with open()`
root = ET.parse('input.xml')

rows = []
for job_node in root.findall('.//JOB'):
    row = dict(Row_Tmpl)  # use dict() to make a copy; don't use it directly

    # Job attributes
    row['JobID'] = job_node.get('JOBID')
    row['JobName'] = job_node.get('JOBNAME')
    row['Type'] = job_node.get('TYPE')
    row['Form'] = job_node.get('FORM')

    # Job's children values
    type_db_node = job_node.find('./VARIABLE[@NAME="%%TYPE_DB"]')
    if type_db_node != None:
        row['Type_DB'] = type_db_node.get('VALUE', 'N/A')

    account_node = job_node.find('./VARIABLE[@NAME="%%ACCOUNT"]')
    if account_node != None:
        row['Account'] = account_node.get('VALUE', 'N/A')

    rows.append(row)
```

Here's what all the data looks like (I added another `JOB` to the input XML for my testing):

```py
import pprint

print('All rows from XML')
pprint.pprint(rows, width=180)
```

```
All rows from XML
[{'Account': 'ONLINE', 'Form': 'Databases', 'JobID': '835', 'JobName': 'JOBA', 'Type': 'db', 'Type_DB': 'Open Query'},
 {'Account': 'ONLINE', 'Form': 'Databases', 'JobID': '839', 'JobName': 'JOBB', 'Type': 'db', 'Type_DB': 'N/A'},
 {'Account': 'ONLINE', 'Form': 'Databases', 'JobID': '842', 'JobName': 'JOBC', 'Type': 'db', 'Type_DB': 'N/A'}]
```

#### Filter w/plain Python

Now, you can filter it, and even modify values however you like, with plain Python:

```py
rows_with_type_db = [x for x in rows if x['Type_DB'] != 'N/A']

print('Rows filtered by Type_DB != N/A')
pprint.pprint(rows_with_type_db, width=180)
```

```
Rows filtered by Type_DB != N/A
[{'Account': 'ONLINE', 'Form': 'Databases', 'JobID': '835', 'JobName': 'JOBA', 'Type': 'db', 'Type_DB': 'Open Query'}]
```

#### Write it

I don't have the module for creating Excel files, but here's how easy it is to create a CSV with the **DictWriter**:

```py
from csv import DictWriter

Fieldnames = Row_Tmpl.keys()
with open('filtered_jobs.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = DictWriter(f, fieldnames=Fieldnames)
    writer.writeheader()
    writer.writerows(rows_with_type_db)
```

| JobID | JobName | Type | Form | Type_DB | Account |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 835 | JOBA | db | Databases | Open Query | ONLINE |